# Windows Phone reading in a pdf using binary reader

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pdf

(Warning: First time on Stackoverflow) I want to be able to read in a pdf via binary but I encounter an issue when writing it back to the isolated storage. When it is written back to isolated storage and I try to open the file but I get an error message from adobe reader saying this is not a valid pdf. The file is 102 Kbytes but when I write it to isolated storage it is 108 Kbytes.

My reasoning for doing this is that I want to be able to split the pdfs. I have tried PDFsharp (doesn't open all pdf types). Here is my code:

```
public void pdf_split()
{
    string prefix = @"/PDFread;component/";

    string fn = originalFile;
    StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(prefix + fn, UriKind.Relative));

    IsolatedStorageFile iStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();


    using (var outputStream = iStorage.OpenFile(sFile, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        Stream resourceStream = sr.Stream;
        long length = resourceStream.Length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        int readCount = 0;

        while (readCount < length)
        {

            int read = sr.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            readCount += read;
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you compared the original and the file from the isolated storage to see what is different? Maybe line endings have changed or some non-ASCII chars were modified.

Comment: I don't think it'll solve your problem, but your code will be way shorter if you use `Stream.CopyTo` to copy the streams rather than doing it manually. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @KooKiz I wish to have a stopping point when I reach certain bytes to split the pdf. So it will have to be done another way.

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam The difference is that there are some extra unidentified characters at the end of the file.